# Xcode 4: "error: unknown type name 'BOOL'; did you mean 'BOOL'?"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, compiler-errors

I have a project which worked great under Xcode 3.2.x. Under Xcode 4.2, I'm getting the following error when compiling:

```
"error: unknown type name 'BOOL'; did you mean 'BOOL'?"
```

I can right click on the offending `BOOL` and Xcode will jump to Apple's definition. `BOOL` is defined in `<objc/objc.h>`, so I included it in my source file (despite the fact that I'm using precompiled headers with UIKit.h and Foundation.h). Still no joy - the compile error persists.

Any ideas for Xcode 4 work arounds would be appreciated. Google is offering 0 hits.

EDIT: added the offending code to remove any ambiguity.

```
// AppConstants.h
typedef enum { ThreadPriorityLow = NSOperationQueuePriorityLow, ThreadPriorityNormal = NSOperationQueuePriorityNormal,
    ThreadPriorityHigh = NSOperationQueuePriorityHigh, ThreadPriorityDefault = ThreadPriorityNormal } ThreadPriority;

static inline BOOL IsValidThreadPriority(ThreadPriority priority)
{
    return priority == ThreadPriorityLow || priority == ThreadPriorityNormal || priority == ThreadPriorityHigh;
}
```

EDIT: after looking at the source under Emacs and HexFiend for illegal characters and finding none (source is 8-bit clean), I'm inclined to believe this is due to some kind of bug on Apple's part.

Comment: Which line of code is triggering this error? Which `BOOL` did you right-click on in that line?

Comment: @BoltClock - "did you right-click on in that line" - Of course I did :)

Comment: Were you still getting the error after including objc.h?  Your question is a little ambiguous on that point.

Comment: @JeremyP - OK, I bite. Why would I ask the question if I had already fixed the problem? Forgive my snippiness - Apple bricked my iPod tonight too.

Comment: @noloader:  The question could have been read as "I got it working by including `objc.h` but is there a better solution"

Comment: @JeremyP - but it did not work after including the objc.h.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was broken Apple software.

Apple disregarded my 3.2.6 projects settings and decided to use the LLVM 3.0 suite rather than GCC 4.2. Previously (under Xcode 3.2.6), I had specifically set the project to use GCC due to my extensive use of GCC warnings and flags.

After I changed 'Build Settings' -> 'Compile for C/C++/Objective' back to GCC 4.2, it worked.

Apple Radar 10278815 reported, and [LLVM Bug 11126](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=11126) reported. Hopefully Apple will fix it before Xcode 5.

Answer (score 3):

A wild guess is a special character that appeared on your line, you were probably using some special character encoding in XCode 3 and opening the file in XCode 4 triggers this error.

To see if this answer is correct I would recommend you `cat` or `vim` the file in your terminal and see if some wild characters are located at this specific line.

Let us know if this works

Comment: @apouche - Under emacs, it looks like all the characters are 8 bit clean.

Comment: (an earlier version of) clang barfed when it encountered a header with a BOM. took hours to find it, and i had to locate the issue by sending it through a trunk build of clang.

Comment: @apouche - Under HexFiend, all the characters on the offending line are 8 bit clean (7 bit ASCII).

Comment: HexFiending was a good idea, you problem seems tricker than it appeared at first. Keep us posted if you find the solution

Comment: @apouche - the answer is below (more broken Apple software).

Comment: @Justin - you should have answered - it was a broken LLVM 3.0 front end.

Comment: @noloader it seemed unlikely that it was an identical problem, i just wanted to point out that these kinds of things do slip through. glad it helped :)