# Unknown type name 'intmax_t'

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm having some serious problems compiling. I'm on Xcode 5. Everything was working, now it's not.

It won't compile my .pch file. I've tried a new .pch file to no avail.

I get hundreds of errors, starting with: Unknown type name 'intmax_t'

Has anyone experienced this and got any pointers to where I might start figuring out why it's doing this? It's got to be a setting in my project file somewhere

Comment: When you're doing the `git bisect` you should clean before every build.

Comment: I did, and deleted derived data. However, my bad on the git bisect comment - it finishes on the last good commit, not the first bad commit. So I did find the commit and kind of found the error. I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue to be:

```
Always Search User Paths: This was set to Yes. 
User Header Search Paths: "$(SRCROOT)/" (recursive)
```

I removed these and all is well again.

Answer (score 0):

that error comes from "stdint.h" not being in your project. (that's where it's defined).  Since that's a core library, it must be that a path has changed some how.  This could happen if you moved your project, renamed the folder, or installed a new version of Xcode and the path is not updated.  It could also happen if the compiler settings were changed. for example, see this question
[Xcode 4: "error: unknown type name 'BOOL'; did you mean 'BOOL'?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7751411/xcode-4-error-unknown-type-name-bool-did-you-mean-bool?rq=1)
as you can see, his compiler was switched on him and he had to change it back.  So you might be using a different compiler without realizing it, so it's looking for the libraries somewhere else.   That you give you some clues.  Let me know what you find

Comment: Well it must be in the project file somewhere, as I have checked it out on the build machine too and I'm getting the same error. I'll look into your suggestions. Thanks